# adding image to database html form

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to add records into a database. Each record has a corresponding image. The records are getting inserted into the database but it is not working for the image. I am getting this error "connected successfully Notice: Undefined variable: sql in C:\xampp\htdocs\Syokimaufc\addplayer.php on line 35 Error: Query was empty" How can i solve this?

```
<form action="addplayer.php"method ="post" enctype="multipart/form-    data">

     <p> id: <input type="text" name="playerid"/></p>
     <p> Name: <input type="text" name="name"/></p>
     <p> Age: <input type="text" name="age"/></p>
     <p> Position: <input type="text" name="position"/></p>
     <p> Nationality: <input type="text" name="nationality"/></p>
     <p> Photo: <input type="file" name="image"/></p>
 <input type="submit"  value="submit"/>

 <form/>



 <?php
require 'connection.php';


$id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'playerid');
$name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name');
$age = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'age');
$position = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'position');
$nationality = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'nationality');

$_id = mysql_real_escape_string( $id );
$_name = mysql_real_escape_string( $name );
$_age = mysql_real_escape_string( $age );
$_position = mysql_real_escape_string( $position );
$_nationality = mysql_real_escape_string( $nationality );

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $imageName = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES ["image"]["name"]);
    $imageData = mysql_real_escape(file_get_contents($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]));
    $imageType = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES["image"]["name"]);

    if (substr($imageType,0,5) == "image")
    {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO players ( playerid, name, age, position, nationality, iname, image ) VALUES ( '$_id', '$_name', '$_age', '$_position', '$_nationality', '$imageName', '$imageData' )";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "only images are allowed";
    }
}


if (!mysql_query($sql)){
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: What is the data type of your `image` column? Is it a [`BLOB`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/blob.html)? Where do you want to store the uploaded images? In a folder in your system or in a `BLOB` column?

Comment: Stop for a moment and think about the overhead for doing mysql_real_escape on very large files. Do you really want to save images in a database?

Answer (score 0):

Put:

```
if (!mysql_query($sql)){
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

Immediately after

```
$sql = "INSERT IN..."
```

The problem is that because you run the query outside of all your `if` checks, the query will be run even when there is no input data (eg: no form was submitted), and `$sql` will be non-existent in that case. Hence the "*Undefined variable: sql*" and the "*Query was empty*" errors